# Fractional scaling in GNOME + Wayland above 200%

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, wayland

I've successfully enabled fractional scaling on my GNOME 3.38 + Wayland in Arch as stated here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Wayland

However, in gnome control center it now only shows 100% 125% 150% 175% and 200% whereas for my screen the best setup would be 250% (that I can set in Windows 10 for example).
How can enable values above 200% in gnome control center or either set it manually?

Comment: You can set integer values in key /org/gnome/desktop/interface/scaling-factor using dconf-editor to set 100%/200%/300% etc ratios.

I reported this question in the feature page on the [bug tracker](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/478).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dconf-editor` to do this.

1. Launch `dconf-editor` app
2. Navigate to /org/gnome/desktop/interface/
3. Open scaling-factor and a dialog appears.
4. You can now set integer values manually at the custom value field e.g 100%, 150%, 250%... ratios.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

You can use the **gsettings** command to modify the scaling-factor setting in the **org.gnome.desktop.interface** schema.

```
# Set the scaling factor to 2.5 (250%)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2.5
```

If you want to set the scaling factor for all users, you can use the ***dconf*** command instead of gsettings. For example:

```
# Set the scaling factor to 2.5 (250%) for all users
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/scaling-factor 2.5
```

Note that you *may need to log out and log back in* for the changes to take effect.

Alternatively, you can use the ***xrandr*** command to set the scaling factor manually. For example:

```
# Set the scaling factor to 2.5 (250%) for the eDP1 display
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 2.5x2.5
```

Comment: `dconf` and `gsettings` write to the same database. `dconf` doesn't magically affect all users. Is this answer generated from ChatGPT or something?